# Python - Return name of state in USA given latitude and longitude

Tags: python, geocoding

Does anyone know of an offline method in Python for returning the USA state, given a lat/lon pair?
I need to run through 700k+ lat/lon pairs, so Google's API is not suitable.

Lat/Lon values are stored in a dataframe, but can be considered a list here.

Example:

```
lat_vals = [32]
lon_vals = [-109]

for lat, lon in zip(lat_vals, lon_vals):
    get_state(lat, lon)

>>> NM
```

Comment: How do you stored data locally ? can you show that too, because if you want to run locally to determine the state from the lat, lon you should ve them locally.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the big amounts of data you have, you might have to consider using [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) to run some analysis with your data. Python doesn't have any good tools for doing spatial analysis, even when your trying to use it with OGR GDAL.

Best bet is to set up a basic PostgreSQL & PostGIS database, use [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) to load your shapefiles in the database **(Database >> Spit >> Import Shapefile to PostgreSQL)**

Then you can run these basic SQL command to extract your data.

```
SELECT states.name, points.name
FROM states, points
WHERE ST_Contains(states.geom, points.geom)
```

To get USA States shapefile data, go to the [Tiger Census Data](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html) page.

If you want to use Python after the data is all loaded, you can use [psycopg2](http://pythonhosted.org//psycopg2/) to connect to your database.

I hope this helps, not a simple solution.